# Pass seperate arguments to the same callback function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to pass different arguments from separate JSON request functions to the same callback function.

```
function getParameters() {
    request('http://private.apiary-mock.com/config/jsonX', function (error, response, body, importedJSON, X) {
        if (error && response.statusCode != 200) {
            throw error;
        }
        importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        X = importedJSON;
        argument.call(this,X);
    });

    request('http://private.apiary-mock.com/config/jsonY', function (error, response, body, importedJSON, Y) {
            if (error && response.statusCode != 200) {
                throw error;
            }
            importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
            Y = importedJSON;
            argument.call(this, Y);
        }
    );
    function argument(X, Y) {
        console.log(X, Y);
     }
}

getParameters();
```

Actually, it finds values, but also calls undefined variables.

```
X undefined
Y undefined
```

I am very new to JS and don't know if it's the right way to pass arguments. Many thanks, for your opinions, or possible solutions.

Looking forward,

Comment: call takes first argument as context

Comment: Only one argument is passed to the function

Comment: Actually, `function argument(X, Y) {...}` is called twice, it is declared in both JSON requests. Every time it takes both arguments X and Y, first time it takes X and finds Y `undefined` and second time vice versa.